# Html ссылки в Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, ссылки, href

Ребят, столкнулся с проблемой. Натягиваю верстку на вордпресс, хочу сделать переход на другую страницу, путем нажатия обычной ссылки ( a href), но после нажатия выскакивает такая страница "403 Access denied". Подскажите что нужно сделать что бы переход осуществлялся.

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: <a href="/http://goodfood.is-great.org/wp-content/themes/lk/anketa.php" class="expand_link read_more anket">Посмотреть анкету<img src="http://goodfood.is-great.org/wp-content/themes/lk/img/expand_image.jpg"></a><br>


Эту?

Comment: в логах это
Tue, 24 May 2016 01:45:35 -0500 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/vol5_7/byethost9.com/b9_17939306/goodfood.is-great.org/htdocs/wp-content/themes/lk/stranica_activov.php

Comment: У вас не правильно использована ссылка.Поставьте ещё один слеш: `<a href="//goodfood.is-great.org/wp-content/themes/lk/anketa.php";` или, если это тот же сайт - `<a href="/wp-content/themes/lk/anketa.php";`

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: В первом случае `//` указывает на необходимость запроса ссылки по тому же протоколу, который использовался для загрузки текущей страницы.

Comment: первый вариант выдает
"Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Не удалось обнаружить DNS-адрес wp-content."
а второй, то де что и было

Comment: @Dzmitri а какая версия у Вас версия вордпресса и не изменяли ли Вы  .htaccess?

Comment: Версия 4.2.2
Файл такой:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Если важно, в консоли появляется такая строка "http://http//goodfood.is-great.org/wp-content/themes/lk/anketa.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"